# Minimum number of jumps to reach end recursion approach

Tags: arrays, c, recursion

I've a small question about recursion. The code below is actually an answer for the question [Minimum number of jumps to reach end](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-jumps-to-reach-end-of-a-given-array/)

```
// C program to find Minimum
// number of jumps to reach end
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Returns minimum number of
// jumps to reach arr[h] from arr[l]
int minJumps(int arr[], int l, int h)
{
    // Base case: when source and destination are same
    if (h == l)
        return 0;

    // When nothing is reachable from the given source
    if (arr[l] == 0)
        return INT_MAX;

    // Traverse through all the points
    // reachable from arr[l]. Recursively
    // get the minimum number of jumps
    // needed to reach arr[h] from these
    // reachable points.
    int min = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = l + 1; i <= h && i <= l + arr[l]; i++) {
        int jumps = minJumps(arr, i, h);
        if (jumps != INT_MAX && jumps + 1 < min)
            min = jumps + 1;
    }

    return min;
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 5 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf(
        "Minimum number of jumps to reach end is %d ",
        minJumps(arr, 0, n - 1));
    return 0;
}
```

When *h==l* and *arr[l]==0* then the function return sth and function ends. Otherwise, it updates a variable socalled *jumps*, but I cannot understand that statement. For example, what's the value of jumps when i=1 or i=2 and so on. In other words, I cannot understand the point of updating process of jumps variable.

Comment: It's unclear to me what your doubt is. I mean... you have noticed that `jumps` is assigned to `min` when the condition are correct and then `min` is returned.

Comment: The line in question defines a variable called `jumps` and assigns a value to it which is the value returned from a _recursive_ call to the function `minJumps()`. That is to say, the same code is executed, but different parameters are passed. The compiler implements these calls in such a way that, for each call to the function, the exact state of the calling function is remembered and is restored when that function returns. I hope this helps somewhat. (I have to say, this example is not the best way to learn recursion. give me a fibonacci sequence any day.)

Comment: Side note: try not to use lowercase `l` as a variable name. It looks an awful lot like the number `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the key is to carefully read and understand the definition of the function:

```
// Returns minimum number of
// jumps to reach arr[h] from arr[l]
int minJumps(int arr[], int l, int h)
```

That's pretty clear.

The job when implementing a recursive function is to break down the problem into base case or cases and also a recursive step that solves one or more smaller problems with recursive calls, then uses the result to solve the overall problem.

The base case here is starting and finishing at the same location. No steps are needed. Return 0.

(The author also treats zero array elements as a special case. That was unnecessary. The program would work the same if these lines were deleted.)

The recursive step implements this idea:

> To get from `l` to `h`, first take one step from `l` to `i` and then (recursively) figure out the min number steps S from `i` to `h`.  The total number of steps is therefore S+1.

What to choose for `i`? The only way to find the least number of steps is to consider *all possibilities* and take the min. Those possibilities are `l+1` through `h`, i.e. an initial step of length 1 all the way up to covering the whole gap from `l` to `h` in a single step (so the second step has length zero).